# Compare string with string-array name in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, string.xml

I am new to android and I have encountered a problem. I would like to compare a String with a name of a string-array value in string.xml.

So for example my string is "img_1". Now I want to search my strings.xml for a string-array with the name "img_1". How do I compare the String with the name of a string-array value?

```
<string-array name="img_0">
    <item>j</item>
    <item>a</item>
    <item>s</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="img_1">
    <item>t</item>
    <item>o</item>
    <item>m</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="img_2">
    <item>p</item>
    <item>r</item>
    <item>o</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: What had you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Resources method getIdentifier(). Provide your string as identifier name in the parameters. The result will be the id of your string array.

Comment: No reason it shouldn't.  Quite a handy little creature this method. Good luck!